# Is it common to use "wanting" in informal English?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **wanting** (adjective) (formal): wanting (in something) not having enough of something. [Oxford Learners Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wanting)
>
> **wanting** (adjective): not having something; lacking. [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wanting)
>
> In fairly rare, formal English, "to be wanting" can mean "to be lacking", "to be deficient". [English Language and Use](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36597/whats-the-difference-between-i-want-and-i-am-wanting)

it seems *wanting* a formal word, but I noticed some people use it in informal English, the following is an example from a social website:

> **I'm really wanting** to sit and watch a movie with my girlfriend. Can anyone recommend a good girlfriend?

First Question, Is it common to use *wanting* in informal English?

Second, what is the meaning of "I'm really wanting" in the above example? Does it mean "I really want" or "I'm really lacking"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**wanting** in the sense of 'lacking' or 'deficient' tends to be used [in writing fairly frequently](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was%20found%20wanting%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), although it is not often heard in the casual conversation of people under the age of 30. Many words are not often heard in the casual conversation of people under the age of 30.

**wanting** in your girlfriend example is a verb, similar to "She is *singing* a song", and there it means "desiring" or "yearning for" or "feeling an urge to do or to have something".  *I've been wanting to see that movie.*